# UITableView issue (iOS)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I wonder why `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function is called when scrolling the UITableView. Does it mean on every scrolling cell configuration code runs again? I have a slowness problem when scrolling the table.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CountryCell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSString *continent = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
NSString *country = [[self.countries valueForKey:continent] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = country;

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, yes, when each new cell is about to scroll onto the screen, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called for each cell. While this may strike you as a performance hit, the alternative (for iOS to create all of the cells up-front) would be worse: If you're finding it slow to create one cell, imagine having to create hundreds, many of which the user may never see. Anyway, the just-in-time nature of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is probably more efficient, both in terms of the up-front performance hit, as well as in terms of precious memory consumption on a small mobile device.

In terms of slow performance, there's nothing here that could be the culprit. A lot of us have `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods that are significantly more complicated and speed is not an issue. Maybe the there are more efficient alternatives to a `valueForKey` lookup that I might advise if you were doing millions of lookups, but for one cell the difference would not be observable to the human eye. I think you have to look elsewhere. Is `titleForHeaderInSection` doing anything strange (i.e. something other that just looking up a value in an array)? Maybe you can share that with us. Maybe something in the UI. Maybe you should run this through the Profiler's "Time Profiler" and maybe something will stick out. But a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` this simple should result in a perfectly smooth user experience.

Comment: I set cell image from the internet in cellForRowAtIndexPath. When scrolling cells are downloading images again. This causes slowness.

Comment: @Oktay Oh, yeah, that would certainly do it. Personally I'd make that request for an image on a background queue and then dispatch the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` back to the main queue when the image download was complete. I'd also cache the thumbnail images so that it wouldn't have to repeatedly request them from the Internet (but you're probably already doing that).

Comment: I should cache images as you said but I don't know how to do it now. I will work on this.

Comment: @Oktay Personally, after I download an image to some working folder, I then copy the images to a special folder I've created in my app's Documents folder. Then my app, when it needs an image, looks for it in the Documents folder, and only if not found does it initiate the background retrieval of the image. There are more sophisticated solutions, but this works well.

Comment: By the way, I don't know how large the images are, but if they're really big, you may want to also have this background process create a thumbnail image for easier use in tableviews. If you want code for thumbnail creation, let me know.

Comment: Images are small sized. Since I use them as a cell image they are icon (75x75 px). I will try something about downloading and saving images. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you scroll the table, cells that dissappear are discarded and cells that appear must be created and configured using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Or better said - cells are not discarded, they are moved to a queue of cells that can be reused and no new cells are created - the reusable cells are taken from the queue and reconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct that cellForRowAtIndexPath is called when scrolling the table, that's exactly what it's for. Every time a new cell shows up during scrolling, a UITableViewCell instance should be created or re-used, and then configured.

Slowness is usually caused by performing an expensive operation in the configuration phase. In your case, the potentially slow operation would be the country lookup.

Answer (score 1):

The method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called for each and every row in your UITableView, when a row disappears from the visible view, its memory is cleared and a new cell that is coming into visibility, for that new memory is allocated (or a older one might be re used) and the new cell is configured using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

It comes to know from this method only that what needs to be configured for this particular cell.

It is slow may be because of for each cell you are performing some heavy operation.